# How to continue iteration through code

Tags: python, iterator, anagram

```
from collections import Counter
import re
def find_anagrams(a):
    A=set((a))
    B=str(A)
    C=sorted((A))
    D=range(0,len(C))


    for i in D:

        if Counter(C[i]) == Counter(C[i+1]):
            print((C[i]),C[i+1])
            return 'These are anagrams'
```

I'm trying to create a code that checks for an anagram but I can't figure out how to make the iterator loop after getting the first correct match. I've tried using `continue` but that didn't seem to work. I feel like this is a simple fix but I've been working on it for the past hour and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right and your function takes a list of strings as parameters, you can find anagrams by this function:

```py
from collections import Counter


def find_anagrams(words):
    for i in range(len(words)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
            if (Counter(words[i]) == Counter(words[j]) and 
                words[i] != words[j]):
                print('Anagrams:', words[i], words[j])
```

It will check every word with every other word in the list, excluding the same ones.

It will produce the following ouput with these parameters:

```
words = ['aab', 'baa', 'abc', 'cba', 'abcd', 'abbd', 'aba']
find_anagrams(words)
```

```
>>> Anagrams: aab baa
>>> Anagrams: aab aba
>>> Anagrams: baa aba
>>> Anagrams: abc cba
```